# Filipina married to EU citizen wanting to live in Spain. Difficulty in applying Schengen Visa for a start

Tags: visa, eu-citizens, schengen, spain, philippine-citizens

I am a Filipina and we recently got married in the UK while I am on a short-term visa. Our plan is to go to Spain and live there. We have difficulty getting accurate information about documents to provide, which is supposedly just our passports, marriage certificate and travel insurance.

We are planning to apply for a Schengen visa when we are back in the Philippines and yet I was rejected once before by the Spanish embassy when we were planning to go as tourists and were not married yet at that time.

It seems that the Spanish embassy in the Philippines is not forthcoming with the rules of Schengen requirements.It is difficult to them and their website it's not so clear either. Now I am worrying I will be rejected again. What is the easiest process to obtain a Schengen visa where they are very straightforward rules and guidelines?

One thread mentioned the Czech Republic embassy in the Philippines. We are just confused with the EU rights of movement that we are supposed to have when going to Spain.

Answer (score 2):

Applying to any country other than Spain will be a waste of your time unless you lie about your plans, which isn't a good idea.

As the spouse of an EU citizen, you are entitled to freedom of movement in the EU when you travel with (or to join) your spouse.  You cannot be denied a visa, therefore, unless you are a threat to public health, public safety, or public policy.  Your prior visa refusal, therefore, should have no bearing on your new visa application (except in the unlikely event that it was refused on one of those grounds).

Furthermore, the visa must be issued free of charge, and the application must be considered on the basis of an accelerated procedure.  So just stop worrying and apply to the Spanish consulate.